# Converting output back to hours minutes seconds, after converting to seconds for comparison

Tags: java

The code I have works and it's almost to where I want it, however I want the system.out to display the fastestrunnertime in Hours minutes and seconds rather than just seconds, however I still NEED to keep my variable s to convert all the time to seconds as a means to compare the data with ease. Just not too sure how to get the output back to hours minutes seconds without disrupting my code.

```
   double fastesttime = 1000000;
   int fastestrunnernumber = 1;
   double slowesttime = -1000000;
   int slowestrunnernumber = -1;



    while (reader.hasNext() ) {

    int runner = reader.nextInt();
    int hours = reader.nextInt();
    int minutes = reader.nextInt();
    double seconds = reader.nextDouble();

    if (minutes < 60 && seconds < 60)  {


        }


    else {
        System.out.println("Runner with invalid time: " + runner );



    }
       double s = ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + (seconds));

       if (s < fastesttime) {
           fastesttime = s;
           fastestrunnernumber = runner;



       }

       if (s > slowesttime) {
           slowesttime = s;
           slowestrunnernumber = runner;


       }



    }






   System.out.println("The fastest runner is " + fastestrunnernumber + " with the time " + fastesttime );

   System.out.println("The slowest runner is " + slowestrunnernumber + " with the time " + slowesttime );

   }

}
```

}

Comment: I don't understand, what makes you think you somehow loose `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds`? Oh, maybe a scope issue, you want to use them outside the `while`? If so, you have to do as you did for `slowestrunnernumber` (i.e. declare them outside the `while`)

Comment: The variables are lost because he reads them all from the reader. Hence, he has only the last.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: keep the original values in new variables (fastest_hour, fastest_minute and so on) or perform a division at the end, like this:

```
int hours=fastesttime/3600;
int rest=fastesttime%3600;
int minutes=rest/60;
int seconds=rest%60;
```

If you look, you will see that these are the opposite operations from the conversion to seconds.

I hope it helps.